# How to check in any file from java code to svn branch

Tags: java, svn

I want to implement a functionality in which I want to do some svn related operations for example:- update, commit, revert etc.. through my Java code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should use `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.exec()` to call the actual commands of SVN.

Or you can directly use library like http://svnkit.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SVNKit http://svnkit.com/.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a pure Java solution - check out [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Subversion Java API](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/javahl/latest/).